# If $K$ and $H$ are subgroups of $G$ and $H \triangleleft K$ then $K \subseteq N(H)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

We can easily prove the truth of this statement. My question is that why do we not simply say $K=N(H)$ $?$

I'd be really grateful for an elaboration on this.

Comment: The statement $K\subseteq N(H)$ does not imply $K\neq N(H)$. Was your question, "Why do we not simply say $K =N(H)$?" There is a proposed answer to that question below, but the original question itself is still unclear.

Comment: @DavidK , yes, that's exactly what I'm inquiring.

Comment: OK, that's a good question then, although it would still be better if you edited the second sentence to clarify what you are asking (in case someone does not read the comments).

Comment: With normalizers and centralizers *always* use a subscript to denote the group with respect to which this is meant, for example $N_G(H)$, the normalizer of $H$ in $G$.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to specify over which group you take the normalizer; I think this will clear the confusion. While it is true that $H\triangleleft K\Rightarrow K = N_K(H)$, it will not always be that $K = N_G(H)$. However, it is true that $K \subseteq N_G(H)$.

For an example of the strict inclusion, take $G =\mathfrak S_4$, $H = \langle(1\,2\,3)\rangle$. Then $K = \langle (1\,2),(1\,2\,3)\rangle\subsetneq N_G(H)$.

Answer (score 1):

A simple example of proper containment is when $H$ is not normal, has a nontrivial normalizer, and $H=K$. In general any proper subgroup of the normalizer that contains $H$ will serve as an example.